# Javascript slot machine how to use if and else if

Tags: javascript, html

My code is supposed to create a slot machine that Create a list with six symbols (`Cherry, Bell, Lemon, Orange, Star, Skull`).

- Create a variable with the starting credit for the user (£1.00).
- Have it so the user has 20p taken away from their credit for their
  go.
- Generate a list with 3 random choices from the symbol list.
- Print out the choices so the user knows the results.
- If the user gets three of a kind for any symbol but the bell or the
  skull, they get 50p added to their credit.
- If the user gets three bells, they get £1.00 added to their credit.
- If the user gets two skulls, they lose £1.00 of their credit.
- If the user gets three skulls, the user loses all their remaining
  credit.

So far this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Fruit Machine</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="randomSlot()"> Click to generate slot values.</button>

<script>
var slots = ["Cherry", "Lemon", "Bell", "Orange", "Star", "Skull"];
var credit=100

function randomSlot(){
    var one=slots[Math.floor(Math.random()*slots.length)];
    var two=slots[Math.floor(Math.random()*slots.length)];
    var three=slots[Math.floor(Math.random()*slots.length)];
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=one+" "+ two +" "+ three
        credit=credit-20
        document.getElementById("credOutput").innerHTML="Credit:" + credit

        if (one==two && one==three && one!="Skull" && one!="Bell") {
            credit=credit+50;
    }
        else if (one==two && one==three && one="Skull"){
            credit=credit-credit;
    }
        else if (one==two||one==three||two=three && one=="Skull"||two=="Skull"){
            credit=credit-100;
    }
        else if (one==two && one==three && one="Bell"){
            credit=credit+100;
    }
        else {
            credit=credit;
    }
}   



</script>
<p id="output"></p>
<p id="credOutput"></p>

</body>
</html> 

 (one==two && one==three && one="Bell"){
            credit=credit+100;
    }
        else {
            credit=credit;
    }
}   



</script>
<p id="output"></p>
<p id="credOutput"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

The error occurs somewhere in the if statements but i'm unsure about how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's all that stuff after the first `</html>`? Is that a copying error?

Comment: You seem to have multiple `<html>` and `<body>` tags. Maybe edit you code to fix and show exactly what you have working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so this line

```
   else if (one==two||one==three||two==three && one=="Skull"||two=="Skull"){
```

is probably wrong. You need parentheses to group the operations as desired.

```
   else if ((one==two||one==three||two==three) && (one=="Skull"||two=="Skull")){
```

Your code was being processed as if you'd written:

```
   else if (one==two || one==three || (two==three && one=="Skull") || two=="Skull"){
```

In general, it's a good idea to use liberal parentheses whenever you have complex expressions with different operators.

You also have several typos where you're using `=` instead of `==` in your comparisons:

```
    else if (one==two && one==three && one="Skull"){
                                          ^
    else if (one==two && one==three && one="Bell"){
                                          ^
```

Comment: Thank you so much I've changed those things and it is working now!